# Bit masking Technique

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I came upon the following loop:

```c
int i=a;
while (i!=0) {
  i = (i-1) & a;
}
```

What is it's significance?  Is it printing all subset bits of `a`?

Comment: Sort of, except of course that it doesn't print anything

Answer (score 1):

Two examples with 'a' having three bits set.

```
a=i(0)=10101,   a=i(0) = 11010
  i(1)=10100,     i(1) = 11000
  i(2)=10001,     i(2) = 10010
  i(3)=10000,     i(3) = 10000
  i(4)=00101,     i(4) = 01010
  i(5)=00100,     i(5) = 01000
  i(6)=00001,     i(6) = 00010
  i(7)=00000,     i(7) = 00000
```

In effect, this function counts down from 'a' to 0, using as many steps, as any counter with as many bits as there are non-zero bits in *a*. The bits are interleaved to the bit positions in *a*, which may have some practical application related e.g. to Morton numbers, or generating a sequence positioned at predetermined bits.

The degenerate case is *a* with all bits shifted to the right (1,3,7,15,...) where the loop simply transforms to `while(i--);`.

Answer (score 1):

### Meaning of and-with-value-minus-one

The pattern of "anding with a value minus one" is used to strip-off the lowest set bit:

```
1101110000000101000         # value
               ^---- bottomost set bit   
1101110000000100111         # value minus one
                  ^-- set to one
                 ^--- set to one
                ^---- set to one
               ^----- reset to zero
```

The subtract-by-one step zeroes to the bottommost set bit, and it sets all the bits below it to one.

The subsequent and-operation then applies that newly zeroed bit to back to `a`.  Bits to the right of zeroed value are left intact (anding with one leaves a bit unchanged).

### Overall Pattern

The loop takes zeroes the bottommost bit and "restores" all bits to the right of that bit.  So, **the OP was correct in surmising the function loops over "all subset bits of *a*".**

Put another way, the code is producing the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of each bit being set and unset.  Accordingly, the number of iterations will be a power of two.

### Example

For example, starting with `a = 37` which is `00100101` in binary, we get the 8-element sequence: `[37, 36, 33, 32, 5, 4, 1, 0]`.

The bit values are `[32, 4, 1]` which is `[00100000, 00000100, 00000001]` in binary.

The sequence is just a sum of products.  Here is a short Python example:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for tup in product([32, 0], [4, 0], [1, 0]):
        print('%2d  = sum(%r) = sum(%r)' % (sum(tup), [format(x, '08b') for x in tup], list(tup)))


37  = sum(['00100000', '00000100', '00000001']) = sum([32, 4, 1])
36  = sum(['00100000', '00000100', '00000000']) = sum([32, 4, 0])
33  = sum(['00100000', '00000000', '00000001']) = sum([32, 0, 1])
32  = sum(['00100000', '00000000', '00000000']) = sum([32, 0, 0])
 5  = sum(['00000000', '00000100', '00000001']) = sum([0, 4, 1])
 4  = sum(['00000000', '00000100', '00000000']) = sum([0, 4, 0])
 1  = sum(['00000000', '00000000', '00000001']) = sum([0, 0, 1])
 0  = sum(['00000000', '00000000', '00000000']) = sum([0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm will calculate all possible subsets of setting the bits of a with using 0 to (n-1) bits set, where n is the total number of bits. A second rule is, that if a bit position in a is zero, it will not be part of this subset.

For example for a = 0b111 (n = 3)

```
i = (i-1) & a (i-1 = 110 (6) a = 111 (7) result 110 (6))
i = (i-1) & a (i-1 = 101 (5) a = 111 (7) result 101 (5))
i = (i-1) & a (i-1 = 100 (4) a = 111 (7) result 100 (4))
i = (i-1) & a (i-1 = 011 (3) a = 111 (7) result 011 (3))
i = (i-1) & a (i-1 = 010 (2) a = 111 (7) result 010 (2))
i = (i-1) & a (i-1 = 001 (1) a = 111 (7) result 001 (1))
i = (i-1) & a (i-1 = 000 (0) a = 111 (7) result 000 (0))
```

What you can see here is all combinations of setting a (0b111 = 3 bits set) with 0, 1 or 2 bits set.

For the second rule have a look on:

```
i = (i-1) & a (i-1 = 101 (5) a = 110 (6) result 100 (4))
i = (i-1) & a (i-1 = 011 (3) a = 110 (6) result 010 (2))
i = (i-1) & a (i-1 = 001 (1) a = 110 (6) result 000 (0))
```